# My C# Windows Form Application doesn't exit after I click close button on caption bar (the (X) button on upper right corner)

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am having 7 forms in my Application and each form has [this.hide()] which hides the current form after opening the next, and the "X" or "Cancel" button doesn't exit the whole Application. it only hides the current form, which is the only one opened.
i don't know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Impossible to tell without further information, such as source code.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I don't think source code is really necessary but i'll give you a flesh-out on what really the problem is. You see, for example you have more than one form in your Application and each form has a button that links or open the second form, and it will hide the current form after opening the next with: take for example     " private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){ this.Hide();  form2 f2 = new form2();   f1.Show(); }". So the Red "X" cancel button doesn't exit the whole Application, instead it hides the current form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone come across such problem the solution is : goto your form closing event and add Application.exit();

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exit the whole application, then use:

```
Application.Exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be a main form in your application - the one that was passed to `Application.Run();`.

So if a form close is requested, you need to close that form. You could try to assign the `Closing` event in all forms and try this:

```
Application.OpenForms[0].Close();
```

What you're doing, however, sounds like really strange design. What I'd do is create *one* main form that has a container. What you have in the other forms now would go into `Usercontrol`s. I'd then make the buttons switch the main form's content to different `UserControl`s.

Comment: Glad it worked! The equivalent of "thank you" would be to upvote/accept the answer :-)